# Views handling in a multi-page real-time, nodejs, express, application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, single-page-application

I'm starting to develop a new NodeJS (with Express) Web / CRUD / REST Multi-page Application and I would like to begin in the best way.

The Application object will have a lot of modules, just for example:

- Users management at several levels with policies for the operations which they can do, based on the the user level.
- Simple forms to insert, update, retrieve database data.
- Screens to display real-time sensors (have already thought to make use of libraries such Socket.io).

The basic application (NodeJS server-side API) will also be "called" by Android / iOS applications to fetch / edit data from mobile.

Considering the project as a multi-page application with many asynchronous calls, I have a doubt about the views management and I would like to figure out which one of the following approaches is the most convenient:

**1 conjecture (PURE API style?)**: write, for each request, an express route that returns only a JSON response and compose the view client-side (startly with simple jquery DOM editing, later with React or Angular), after downloading the same (via socket or ajax call).

***Server side***:

1 Call: /getFooView

```
router.get('/getFooView', function(req, res, next) {
    //code
    res.send(htmlview);
});
```

2 Call: /getFooData

```
router.get('/getFooView', function(req, res, next) {
    //code
    res.json({"foo": "bar"});
});
```

***Client side***:

Javascript / JQuery client-side will compose the "getFootView" then it will be showed to the user.

**2 conjecture**: write, for each request, an express route that returns the view (usually a tiny html block, list or similar) already composed server-side (let's suppose by handlerbars). In this case, each controller route should interpret the request according to the requester.

***Server side***:

```
router.get('/getFoo', function(req, res, next) {

    // pseudo code

    if(request == "ANDROID" || request == "iOS")
        res.json({data});

    else
    res.render('index', {
    // handlebars parsed view
        title: blockTitle,

        data: blockData

        sensors: sensorsData

    });
});
```

***Client Side:***
JQuery code to append the received block.

Which approach is better suited to my purpose? What are the pros and cons?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If we talk about single-page-application, then you shouldn't send views. You can use nginx for client files including css, html, js and etc. Also nginx will caching and proxing client requests to you REST API.

So my answer is **PURE API + nginx for static files**.

Comment: Man i'm talking about NodeJS. Can't understand Nginx use. Why should i use it and can't use node / express "gets" to serve views?

Comment: If your backend make views, then you haven't single-page-application.
Your backend with Node.js should make only one thing - implement REST API. Then you can use it for web and mobile.